# external USB NTFS drive unmount during file operation

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

I recently installed (with format disk option) a clean Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. (all new and shinny, no junk / custom setup of any kind except VS, Unity and other out of the box stuff)

With ultracopier 2.2.4.7, I copied 500gb of files from a exernal usb NTFS drive to another (same model) external disk.

At some point, the copy start failing. I notice the destination drive unmounted. making smaller copy, that is less files per copy, it kind of works better. Until I could not mount again the destination drive (error "(udisk-error-quark, 0)") anymore. Using "disk", I "repair filesystem" of the partition, which seem to solve the mouting filesystem problem.

**But now, I notice the destination drive (Joshua4TB) will unmount and remount it self when doing important file operation. For example, displaying the properties of a folder with 33'000 files approx.**

I did not have this kind of issue on Ubuntu 16. Notice the destination disk is also completely new.

Using disk "check filesystem", no error are found, and doing "repair filesystem" again result in success.(but it is unclear to me if something was indeed fixed)

How can I fix the drive ? what is the problem ?

/var/log/syslog
entries: between an auto mount, an error, an auto unmount , and the auto mount

```
Apr 16 02:07:59 buntu systemd-udevd[11443]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 16 02:07:59 buntu systemd-udevd[11443]: sdc1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc1' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 16 02:07:59 buntu kernel: [ 9491.528096] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Version 2021.8.22 integrated FUSE 28
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 (Read-Write, label "Joshua4TB", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Cmdline options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names,uhelper=udisks2
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Mount options: nodev,nosuid,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,rw,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdc1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu udisksd[826]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/gm/Joshua4TB on behalf of uid 1000
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu dbus-daemon[1489]: [session uid=1000 pid=1489] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=1656 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Apr 16 02:08:02 buntu dbus-daemon[1489]: [session uid=1000 pid=1489] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691265] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 23
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691424] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691498] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691510] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 44 83 4b 48 00 00 00 08 00 00
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691515] I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1149455176 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691619] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1149455176 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.691637] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 143681641, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.692665] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1149750088 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.692686] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1149750088 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.692689] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 143718505, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.693077] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1150634824 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.693099] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1150634824 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.693103] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 143829097, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.699185] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1150929736 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.699207] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 1150929736 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.699210] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 143865961, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700264] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 324936 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700281] device offline error, dev sdc, sector 324936 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700283] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 40361, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700497] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 40361, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700787] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 144087145, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.700979] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 124271055, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.701099] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 124271055, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu kernel: [ 9581.701335] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 124271055, async page read
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu udisksd[826]: Cleaning up mount point /media/gm/Joshua4TB (device 8:33 no longer exists)
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read index block: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu systemd[1]: media-gm-Joshua4TB.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read index block: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read index block: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read index block: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read of MFT, mft=145041 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read of MFT, mft=145042 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read index block: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read vcn 0x1 from inode 138980: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
[this repeat for a while]
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Failed to read vcn 0x0 from inode 138978: Input/output error
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu ntfs-3g[11456]: Unmounting /dev/sdc1 (Joshua4TB)
Apr 16 02:09:29 buntu nautilus[4229]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.059279] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.080020] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=2621, bcdDevice=10.34
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.080025] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.080027] usb 4-1: Product: Elements 2621
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.080029] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.080031] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 57584532443932385241465A
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.081700] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu kernel: [ 9582.082032] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 24: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 24 was not an MTP device
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 24: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Apr 16 02:09:30 buntu mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 24 was not an MTP device
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.112431] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 2621    1034 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.112898] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113122] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113270] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 7813969920 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113273] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113569] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113572] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113863] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.113865] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.301681]  sdc: sdc1
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.301883] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu systemd-udevd[11517]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu systemd-udevd[11517]: sdc1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc1' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 16 02:09:31 buntu kernel: [ 9583.758705] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
```

sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdc1

```
/dev/sdc1:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD40NDZW-11BCSS0                    
    Serial Number:     [REDACTED]
    Firmware Revision:  01.01A01
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x006d) 
    Supported: 10 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 10
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   0
    heads       16  0
    sectors/track   63  0
    --
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  7813971632
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     3815415 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     4000753 MBytes (4000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 4800
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
    Advanced power management level: 128
    DMA: *mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    NCQ priority information
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
       *    Device encrypts all user data
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 255 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    772min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee26ad12f84
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 0014ee
    Unique ID   : [REDACTED]
Checksum: correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... I had at least one problem, maybe two. both hardware.

same hard drive work fine on another computer.

1. my OS 5yr+ ssd harddrive  was having issue. A scan on the disk helped, but did not solve the problem. actually, it stop booting altogether recently...
2. I suspect the usb controller was also misbehaving. But my *nix-fu is too weak to actually diagnose this with certainty.